# How to delete a column in Parse.com using Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform

How do I delete a column in Parse using Swift? I am new to Parse. I have looked at the Parse documentation, but could not figure it. After trying many variations of the docs in my code nothing has worked. If it is not possible to delete a column, then how do I delete a row.

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does. It'll delete the new instance of the "QuestionsAndAnswers" PFObject that you've just created (and it won't even do that really, because you haven't saved it to the server), not the whole class. I don't believe you can remove the whole class via the API, you can only remove objects/instances of the class.

Comment: The best you can do in the API is to delete all rows using delete all, as parse API does not support drop classes from the API only from the webpage

Comment: If you want to delete a class permanently, the option is available on the Parse website.

Answer (score 1):

In your example code, `QuestionsandAnswers` is an object, not a class.

If you really intend to delete a class, that is now possible with the Schema API that the Parse team just released: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/releasing-the-schema-api/

Here is the specific documentation for removing a class which you can do with cURL or Python: https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#schemas

Good luck (and be careful). :)